# Disable printing all possibilities in tcsh on TAB

Tags: command-line, autocomplete, tcsh

Earlier, in my shell, on pressing TAB, I would directly see the directory path completed to the best length possible. But now, after upgrading to centos-6 I see that it also prints all possible names from the current directory and then completes the command which seems to be unnecessarily take up space in my shell as some of the directories I work with have 100s of subdirectories starting with the same name.
How can I revert it so that I only get completion and not see all directories printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `unset autolist`?  Test it on the command-line and if it works, add it to your `~/.tcshrc`

see `man tcsh` and search for `Completion and listing` for more details on completion and on what autolist does.

Comment: Dead on! That works :)